# Go To Statement Considered Harmful?

Tags: c#, .net, goto, base-class-library

If the statement above is correct, then why when I use reflector on .Net BCL I see it is used a lot?

EDIT: let me rephrase: are all the GO-TO's I see in reflector written by humans or compilers?

Comment: great question, i was told that goto is like the banned apple in paradise. My teacher (C/C++ lesson) told us that when he sees anyone in the cass using goto will autoamticaly fail the class :)

Comment: @Gabriel You may want to find a new teacher.

Comment: @Neil He was the best teacher i ever had. And he knew what he was taking about. It was hard work to pass his class (even with the lowest grade) but when you finished it, you could say you improved your programming skills by a magnitude.

Comment: @Gabriel Well, IMHO a blanket ban on any language feature is wrong. You should instead be taught what the correct place to use such a feature is.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth:  A blanket ban on a language feature can be the right thing to do in an educational context, depending on teachers, students, and what's being taught.  If I were teaching an introductory C++ course, for example, I wouldn't want to see certain C features, and I might ban them.

Comment: Goto... once you understand why you should never use it under any circumstances and are capable of writing any program without it, then you may use it.

Comment: Yaron, you  may consider rephrasing the question again. Whether ALL the goto's you see in Reflector is either written as such by a human, or generated by the compiler really depends on what you have loaded in Reflector.

Comment: Frank Rubin published a criticism of Dijkstra's letter in the March 1987 CACM where it appeared under the title 'GOTO Considered Harmful' Considered Harmful.[7] The May 1987 CACM printed further replies, both for and against, under the title '"GOTO Considered Harmful" Considered Harmful' Considered Harmful?.[8] Dijkstra's own response to this controversy was titled On a Somewhat Disappointing Correspondence.[9]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The above isn't really correct - it was [a polemical device used by Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful) at a time when gotos were about the only flow control structure in use. In fact, several people have produced rebuttals, including Knuth's classic "Structured Programming Using Goto" paper (title from memory). And there are some situations (error handling, state machines) where gotos can produce clearer code (IMHO), than the "structured" alternatives.

Comment: I agree, +1 for the scientifical perspective. An enumerator is a perfect example for a state machine.

Comment: It wasn't even a polemic device of Dijkstra's. As the wikipedia article points out he didn't choose the title for that paper. Ironic that he should be so famous for that title.

Comment: @Eric If something is published under your name, you are responsible for it - no-one else. And Dijkstra has a few other polemical goodies to his name.

Comment: So @Neil, just to be clear, it is your position that if an editor changes the title of your article and publishes it without running it by you first, you're responsible, and no one else is responsible. Yes?

Answer (score 25):

I think the following excerpt from the [Wikipedia Article on Goto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto) is particularly relevant here:

> Probably the most famous criticism of
>   GOTO is a 1968 letter by Edsger
>   Dijkstra called Go To Statement
>   Considered Harmful.  In that letter
>   Dijkstra argued that unrestricted GOTO
>   statements should be abolished from
>   higher-level languages because they
>   complicated the task of analyzing and
>   verifying the correctness of programs
>   (particularly those involving loops).
>   An alternative viewpoint is presented
>   in Donald Knuth's Structured
>   Programming with go to Statements 
>   which analyzes many common programming
>   tasks and finds that in some of them
>   GOTO is the optimal language construct
>   to use.

So, on the one hand we have [Edsger Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_W._Dijkstra) (a incredibly talented computer scientist) arguing *against* the use of the `GOTO` statement, and specifically arguing against the **excessive** use of the `GOTO` statement on the grounds that it is a much less structured way of writing code.

On the other hand, we have [Donald Knuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) (another incredibly talented computer scientist) arguing that using `GOTO`, especially using it judiciously can actually be the "best" and most optimal construct for a given piece of program code.

Ultimately, IMHO, I believe both men are correct.  Dijkstra is correct in that *overuse* of the `GOTO` statement certainly makes a piece of code less readable and less structured, and this is certainly true when viewing computer programming from a purely theoretical perspective.

However, Knuth is also correct as, in the "real world", where one must take a *pragmatic* approach, the `GOTO` statement when used wisely can indeed be the best choice of language construct to use.

Comment: FWIW, some of Knuth's proposed uses for `goto` have been subsumed by other constructs (like `break`) in more modern languages.

Comment: @David - Agreed.  After all, it was 1974 when Donald Knuth published "Structured Programming With Goto Statements".  His paper is as old as I am!  :)

Comment: +1: This is the most balanced answer I've read in this thread, with the added virtue that it does not misrepresent what Dijkstra wrote.

Comment: I think if the program requires speed (like GPU programming or something similar) then goto may be taken into use (perhaps some hardware-related quick enough software design) usually they are not big programs and can end up on 2 to 8kb in total - correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 11):

These `goto`'s are very often generated by the compiler, especially inside enumerators.
The compiler *always* knows what she's doing.

If you find yourself in the need to use `goto`, you should make sure it is the only option. Most often you'll find there's a better solution.

Other than that, there are very few instances the use of `goto` can be justified, such as when using nested loops. Again, there are other options in this case still. You could break out the inner loop in a function and use a return statement instead. You need to look closely if the additional method call is really too costly.

---

In response to your edit:

No, not all gotos are compiler generated, but a lot of them result from compiler generated state machines (enumerators), switch case statements or optimized if else structures. There are only a few instances you'll be able to judge whether it was the compiler or the original developer. You can get a good hint by looking at the function/class name, a compiler will generate "forbidden" names to avoid name clashes with your code. If everything looks normal and the code has not been optimized or obfuscated the use of goto is probably intended.

Answer (score 8):

Keep in mind that the code you are seeing in Reflector is a disassembly -- Reflector is looking at the compiled byte codes and trying to piece together the original source code.

With that, you must remember that rules against `goto`s apply to high-level code.  All the constructs that are used to replace `goto`s (`for`, `while`, `break`, `switch` etc) all compile down to code using JMPs.

So, Reflector looks at code much like this:

```
A:
    if !(a > b)
        goto B;
    DoStuff();
    goto A;
B:  ...
```

And must realize that it was actually coded as:

```
 while (a > b)
    DoStuff();
```

Sometimes the code being read to too complicated for it to recognize the pattern.

Comment: Right you are James, when you get down to the metal (or virtual metal in this case) it (flow control) is all just jumps (goto) with or without a condition.

Answer (score 4):

`Go To` statement itself is not harmful, it is even pretty useful sometimes. Harmful are users who tend to put it in inappropriate places in their code.

Answer (score 4):

When compiled down to assembly code, all control structured and converted to (un)conditional jumps. However, the optimizer may be too powerful, and when the disassembler cannot identify what control structure a jump pattern corresponds to, the always-correct statement, i.e. `goto label;` will be emitted.

This has nothing to do with the harm(ful|less)ness of `goto`.

Answer (score 3):

what about a double loop or many nested loops, of which you have break out, for ex.

```
 foreach (KeyValuePair<DateTime, ChangedValues> changedValForDate in _changedValForDates)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> TypVal in changedValForDate.Value.TypeVales)
                {
                    RefreshProgress("Daten werden geändert...", count++, false);

                    if (IsProgressCanceled)
                    {
                        goto TheEnd; //I like goto :)
                    }
                }
            }
TheEnd:
```

in this case you should consider that here the following should be done with break:

```
  foreach(KeyValuePair<DateTime, ChangedValues> changedValForDate in _changedValForDates)
    {
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> TypVal in changedValForDate.Value.TypeVales)
                    {
                        RefreshProgress("Daten werden geändert...", count++, false);

                        if (IsProgressCanceled)
                        {
                            break; //I miss goto :|
                        }
                    }

                 if (IsProgressCanceled)
                 {
                            break; //I really miss goto now :|
                 }//waaaAA !! so many brakets, I hate'm
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The general rule is that you don't need to use `goto`. As with any rule there are of course exceptions, but as with any exceptions they are few.

The `goto` command is like a drug. If it's used in limited amounts only in special situations, it's good. If you use too much all the time, it will ruin your life.

When you are looing at the code using Reflector, you are not seeing the actual code. You are seeing code that is recreated from what the compiler produced from the original code. When you see a `goto` in the recreated code, it's not certain that there was a `goto` in the original code. There might be a more structured command to control the flow, like a `break` or a `continue` which has been implemented by the compiler in the same way as a `goto`, so that Reflector can't tell the difference.

Answer (score 1):

> `goto` considered harmful (for human to use but
>   for computers its okay).

because no matter how madly we(human) use `goto`, *compiler always knows how to read the code.*

Believe me...

Reading others code with `goto`s in it is HARD.
 Reading your own code with `goto`s in it is HARDER.

That is why you see it used in low level (machine languages) and not in high level (human languages e.g. C#,Python...) ;)

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes use goto when I want to perform a termination action:

```
static void DoAction(params int[] args)
{
  foreach (int arg in args)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(arg);
    if (arg == 93) goto exit;
  }

  //edit:
  if (args.Length > 3) goto exit;
  //Do another gazillion actions you might wanna skip.

  //etc.
  //etc.

exit:
  Console.Write("Delete resource or whatever");
}
```

So instead of hitting `return`, I send it to the last line that performs another final action I can refer to from various places in the snippet instead of just terminating.

Comment: For this, I use `try .. finally`, and `return`.

Comment: Looks you didn't understand my snippet. What does a try help you here? you probably stopped on the "delete resource", but you forgot that it also says "whatever".

Comment: @Shimmy - I have looked at your example closely, and I fail to see why a `try{...}finally{...}` construct wouldn't be ideal for this situation, or why doing more than deleting a resource might be a factor. (Perhaps you are thinking of `using` which creates a `try{...}finally{...}` block and calls `Dispose()`?) Could you please provide more details on why a `goto` is better than a `finally` in this situation?

Comment: Jeffrey, try/finlly would be equivalent, except when an exception is thrown. In the case above the the exit code will not run if an exception is thrown before it (this may be the desired behaviour, or a bug). You could replicate the exact flow of Shimmy's example without using a goto, but one needs to be careful that you don't write convoluted code just to avoid using goto. The reason to avoid goto is because it can turn your code into spaghetti, but I have seen programmers turn their code into spagbol just to avoid using goto. Optimize for legibility.

Answer (score 1):

"C provides the infinitely-abusable goto statement, and labels to branch to. Formally, the goto is *never* necessary, and in practice it is almost always easy to write code without it. We have not used goto in this book."

-- **K&R** (2nd Ed.) : Page 65

Answer (score 1):

In decompiled code, virtually all `goto`s that you see will be synthetic. Don't worry about them; they're an artifact of how the code is represented at the low level.

As to valid reasons for putting them in your own code? The main one I can think of is where the language you are using does not provide a control construct suitable for the problem you are tackling; languages which make it easy to make custom control flow systems typically don't have `goto` at all. It's also always possible to avoid using them at all, but rearranging arbitrarily complex code into a while loop and lots of conditionals with a whole battery of control variables... that can actually make the code even *more* obscure (and slower too; compilers usually aren't smart enough to pick apart such complexity). The main goal of programming should be to produce a description of a program that is both clear to the computer and to the people reading it.

Comment: You mean that the real source code does not contain goto, just the decompiled code?

Comment: @Yaron: He means that the decompiled code will likely contain gotos, whether the original source had it or not. All the flow control structures are ultimately constructed from jumps (gotos) when you dig down deep enough. You are likely to see it in decompiled code when the decompiler cannot infer the original control structure, or when the flow control structure is just cleaner way of using goto (e.g. switch/case, break, continue) anyway.

Comment: @Andre: Right. @Yaron: Decompilers can't handle every way of using every control construct; they're deliberately not the smartest tool ever, because that makes them more likely to go wrong, and fundamental correctness is better than being able to make some situations prettier. Decompilation was always only ever a poor second to *actually having the source*.

Answer (score 0):

If it's harmful or not, it's a matter of likes and dislikes of each one. I personally don't like them, and find them very unproductive as they attempt maintainability of the code.

Now, one thing is how gotos affect our reading of the code, while another is how the jitter performs when found one. From [Eric Lippert's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/04/how-many-passes.aspx), I'd like to quote:

> We first run a pass to transform loops into gotos and labels.

So, in fact the compiler transforms pretty each flow control structure into goto/label pattern while emitting IL. When reflector reads the IL of the assembly, it recognizes the pattern, and transforms it back to the appropriate flow control structure.

In some cases, when the emitted code is too complicated for reflector to understand, it just shows you the C# code that uses labels and gotos, equivalent to the IL it's reading. This is the case for example when implementing `IEnumerable<T>` methods with `yield return` and `yield break` statements. Those kind of methods get transformed into their own classes implementing the `IEnumerable<T>` interface using an underlying state machine. I believe in BCL you'll find lots of this cases.

Answer (score 0):

GOTO can be useful, if it's not overused as stated above. Microsoft even uses it in several instances within the .NET Framework itself.

Comment: What does this provide that the other 13 answers does not?

Answer (score 0):

These goto's are very often generated by the compiler, especially inside enumerators. The compiler always knows what she's doing.

If you find yourself in the need to use goto, you should make sure it is the only option. Most often you'll find there's a better solution.

Other than that, there are very few instances the use of goto can be justified, such as when using nested loops. Again, there are other options in this case still. You could break out the inner loop in a function and use a return statement instead. You need to look closely if the additional method call is really too costly.